# Database table relationships, specify the required conditions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I need to know if a user ordered a product.
There are tables in my database:

1. "carts_products" with columns "cart_id" and "product_id"
2. "сarts" with the "customer_id" column
3. "orders" with column "cart_id" and "customer_id"

I need to find out if "customer" made an order with "product_id"

```
            $cartsCount = Cart::query()
            ->join('cart_products', 'carts.id', '=', 'cart_products.cart_id')
            ->where('product_id', $data['product_id'])
            ->where('customer_id', $data['customer_id'])
            ->count();
```

Here's what I was able to achieve. This is where I get the number of entries for the cart. The "count" approach is probably not even correct.

Carts migration

```
        Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
        $table->integer('recipient_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('recipient_id')->references('id')->on('recipients');
        $table->integer('address_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses');
        $table->integer('payment_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('payment_id')->references('id')->on('payments');
        $table->integer('package_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('package_id')->references('id')->on('packages');
        $table->string('discount_title')->nullable();
        $table->integer('discount_percent')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('reserved')->default(0);
        $table->string('note')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Orders migration

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('cart_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('cart_id')->references('id')->on('carts');
        $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
    });
```

Cart_products migration

```
        Schema::create('cart_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('cart_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('cart_id')->references('id')->on('carts');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->integer('product_mod_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('product_mod_id')->references('id')->on('product_mods');
        $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('reserve')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->integer('release')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->float('price')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->float('discount_amount')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('discount_percent')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->text('note')->nullable();
        $table->text('error')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('showcase')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->boolean('sale')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->boolean('active')->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Customers migration

```
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('gender_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('gender_id')->references('id')->on('genders');
        $table->unsignedInteger('city_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->string('firstname')->nullable();
        $table->string('lastname')->nullable();
        $table->string('thirdname')->nullable();
        $table->string('nickname')->nullable()->unique();
        $table->string('phone')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamp('birthday')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('referrer_rewarded_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('logged_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSkFT.png)

Comment: Welcome. When you post code, it helps if you post example data, what result you're currently getting from that example data and what you expect to get from it. This is specially important when asking about database queries.

Comment: Do you keep your cart information for ever?

Comment: How are you approaching this? Do you ask did this user (user x) buy this product OR which users bought this product OR are you after a report of who bought which products

Comment: @RiggsFolly data is written to the table forever

Comment: ...or how many of said the product that specific user bought?

Comment: A cart is only valid until it becomes a purchase. Once that happens it should be removed, so if the same user returns they start a new cart. You dont keep the same shopping cart when you visit the super markek do you?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson in my example, I link tables into one according to the conditions, if there is at least one record, then the user added this product to the cart, but I need to find out if he made an order

Comment: So the questions is looking like "Did this user actually buy what they put in the cart" Is that the right question for building this query

Comment: How are you expecting us to be able to tell you how to identify if the user actually made an order? We have _no clue_ what your actual flow looks like. Again, please post all relevant information (table schemas, example data, expected result, current result) or all we can do us assume and guess, which isn't constructive for anyone. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i add my migrations

Comment: @RiggsFolly i edit my question and added my migrations

Answer (score 0):

OK first you got to get your realtions working good then you can get the right data out of your query.

Based on your question.

A customer can make orders and orders contain products.

so you need to make a Model based realtion between the 3 then with the query help you can get the data.

Customer -> HasMany -> orders
Orders -> HasMany -> Products

Products -> BelongsToMany -> Orders
Orders -> BelongTo Customer

Once you denfine that in your models you will be able to get the data.

then you can do :

```
    $cartCount = Customer::Where('id', $customerId)
  ->with('orders')
  ->whereHas('orders', function ($q) use ($row) {
  $q->where('product_id', $productId);
      })
    ->first();
```

Something like that will work.

Comment: Suggestion you might want to change update  `->wiht` to `->with` also is there a reason for the closure because I see it's not been used? Also, you can do a `first()` rather than the `count()` since we just want to check if they ordered or not ...

Comment: Table customers do not exist data on orders, only id and others user characteristics

Comment: @Sergeyit is better if you add a customer table.

Comment: @MoubarakHayal ok, customers migration added